# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n[(n+1)^b - n^b-((n+1)^a - n^a)]$ where $0 < a < b<\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis

Find  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n[(n+1)^b - n^b-((n+1)^a - n^a)]$ where $0 < a < b<\frac{1}{2}$.

I was trying to use the binomial theorem for any rational index $a,b$ but they are not given to be rational in this question. Further I tried to use the fact that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ((n+1)^{a}-n^a) =0 $ for $a\in(0,1)$. But I could not find anything fruitful. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Use the binomial series this way: $$
(n + 1)^a  - n^a  = n^a \left( {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^a  - 1} \right) = n^a \left( {1 + \frac{a}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right) - 1} \right) = an^{a - 1}  + \mathcal{O}(n^{a - 2} ).
$$ The binomial series works for all complex $a$.

Comment: So, if I plug in this expression, I would have to find the limit of $n[bn^{b-1}-an^{a-1}+ O(n^{b-2})]$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So any idea what should be the limit of $bn^b -a n^a$?

Comment: You should be able to figure that out yourself given that $0<a<b<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $(bn^b-an^a)$ is an increasing function of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

After using Binomial series, we just have to evaluate

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} bn^b - an^a &=  \lim_{n \to \infty} n^b\left(b-\frac{a}{n^{b-a}}\right) = \infty
\end{align}